# Sitecore - Upload File Error in Media Library

Tags: sitecore, media

When I click on the "Upload File" button in the Sitecore Media Library, an Exception is thrown. The "Upload Files (Adavanced)" button works fine.

[image]

This is the error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   Sitecore.Text.UrlString.Add(String key, String value) +149
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Media.Upload.Run(ClientPipelineArgs args) +1801
   Sitecore.Intranet.Commands.Media.Upload.RunOverridden(ClientPipelineArgs args) +421

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +1255
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args) +318
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +330
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args) +208
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +182
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines() +280
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +530
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

Any idea how I can fix this? Alternativly I would like to hide the "Upload File" button. How can I do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: what version of sitecore do you have?

Comment: Can you check with firebug or chrome inspector what is the url of the request when you click on the button?

Comment: This is the anchor I got from Firebug: <a class="scOption" onclick="javascript:scForm.getParentForm().invoke('media:upload(load=1)');return false" href="#">. It's Sitecore 6.6.

Comment: can you try the upload button on other browsers ? for sitecore 6.6 I recommend to download this extension on chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en and try the upload button there.

Comment: Just gave a try on Chrome and the button works! But it doesn't work on Firefox and IE. Unfortunalety Firefox is a must here. An alternative would be to hide this button if it cannot be fixed. How can I do this?

Comment: Any Javascript errors in IE or Firefox? I seem to recall it is not possible to remove those buttons easily.

Comment: I think you can go to the core database, to this folder /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors/Media/Media Folder/Buttons/Upload and remove the button you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button was not working with you only in firefox.

**You can hide it** by going to the core database, and remove this item

**/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors/Media/Media Folder/Buttons/Upload - Multi**

I tested it, and it works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the path of the item. I now changed the "Upload File" button so that it opens the Batch Upload dialog :)